# best practice for conditional injection of service into a controller for AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a question regarding dependency injection in angular. The tldr to this question is: is there a way to tell Angular to not inject all the dependencies you asked for - so that it doesn't throw an error. The reason why I want this functionality is because I'm using a controller for both a regular route (/addPlayer) and a modal that allows users to add players. In other words, I have addPlayer.html and its controller addPlayer.js. 
I want to allow users to add users also through a modal. This modal uses the addPlayer.html AND the addPlayer.js. However, when using a modal, I need $modalInstance to be injected. When not using modal, I do not need $modalInstance injected. Currently my code gives me an error when I access '/addPlayer' because it says it can't find $modalInstance.

More details:

I have a page (/sportsTeams, controlled by SportsTeamsCtrl) that has a list of players for the user to select. One of the options is "--- Add New Player ---", which when selected, will trigger a modal opening, allowing the user to add a new player.

My code looks something like this:

First, I have a controller for the page (/sportsTeams) where users can select/add players. This controller has an option for launching a new modal, which uses a function that I've defined in the 'ModalsService'. The reason why I have written a ModalsService is because I want to be able to add players from various other pages, and I don't want to write the same code over and over.

```
App.controller('SportsTeamsCtrl', function($scope, ModalsService) {

    $scope.selectOption = function(option) {
       if (option == '--- Add New Player ---') {
           ModalsService.launchPlayerModal().then(function(newOption) {
              $scope.player = newOption;
           }, function(err) {
              console.log(err);
           });
       }
    }
}
```

Then, my 'ModalsService', looks like so:

```
App.factory('ModalsService', function($modal, $q) {

  var launchPlayerModal = function() {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    var modalInstance = $modal.open({
      templateUrl: '/partials/addPlayer.html',
      controller: 'AddPlayerCtrl',
      size: 'lg',
      resolve: {
        isModal: function() {return true;}
      }
    });
    modalInstance.result.then(function(selectedPlayer) {
      deferred.resolve(selectedPlayer);
    }, function() {
      deferred.reject();
      console.log('modal dismissed at ' + new Date());
    });
    return deferred.promise;
  };

}
```

As you can see, the 'launchPlayerModal' function in the ModalsService calls the $open function provided by $modal. It uses the 'AddPlayerCtrl'. It returns a promise.

Now, here is where I am having issues. Within 'AddPlayerCtrl', I have the following code

```
App.controller('AddPlayerCtrl', function($scope, isModal, $modalInstance) {

  $scope.isModal = isModal;

  $scope.addPlayer = function(player) {

      addPlayerToDatabase(category).then(function(data) {

        if ($scope.isModal) {
          $modalInstance.close(data);
        }

      }, function(err) {
        console.log(err);
      });
  };
}
```

So the issues I'm having are because of one simple reason: I'd like to use this 'SportsTeamCtrl' as a controller for modals AND regular routes to '/addPlayer'. Basically, when my site goes to '/addPlayer', I'd like to use the 'AddPlayerCtrl'. PLUS, when I have a page that has a list of drop down selections for selecting a player and one of the selections will launch a modal for adding a player, I'd like to use this SAME 'AddPlayerCtrl'.

The problem is that I ONLY need $modalInstance to be injected when I'm using a modal. If I'm not using a modal, I don't need $modalInstance to be injected.

Currently, when I go to '/addPlayer', I get the following error:

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $modalInstanceProvider <- $modalInstance
```

I understand why I'm getting this error - it's because when I go to '/addPlayer', $modal.open is not injecting $modalInstance.

So my question is this - what's the best way to conditionally inject $modalInstance or any service.

Also, I get that I may get a lot of responses saying I should just have two separate controllers, one for '/addPlayer' routes and one for modals that load 'addPlayer' content. I understand I can use controller inheritance, but I wasn't sure if this was the best way.

Comment: How did you solve this? I have the exact same problem. I need to inject $uibModalInstanceProvider only when used as modal

Answer (score 2):

You should make 2 separate controllers and push the shared logic into a service.

Then injected the shared logic service into both controllers.

Hope this helps.

Comment: OK this helps. A lot...But I have to ask - is there a reason why having 1 controller like how I wanted to do it isn't a smart idea?

Comment: typically 1 html partial has 1 controller, controllers should only have logic that binds/shows data, business logic should go into services

Comment: so are you suggesting i have a separate "addPlayer.html" for /addPlayer and another "addPlayerModal.html" for the modal? Even when they are almost exactly the same thing? Also, by business logic, what do you mean? the function I've written for adding a player to the database in 'AddPlayerCtrl' should is considered business logic?

Comment: If it's the same html, you can push it into a directive and stamp it on both addPlayer.html and addPlayerModal.html.  Yes you can push that into a service and just call playerService.addPlayer().

Answer (score 1):

`$injector` can help you with this.

- [`Angular $injector` docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/service/$injector)
- [Another very good article](http://phonegap-tips.com/articles/conditional-dependency-injection-with-angularjs.html)